Django's makemessages generates corrupt po file
Django 4.2.16
My code contains this line (beside lots more i18n texts):
filter_text = _('Filter')

I generate the "de" locale po file:
django-admin makemessages --locale de -i venv

The resulting po file is corrupt (see missing prefix "#:"):
#: .\oam\views\article\article_list.py:138
#: .\oam\views\fillup\fillup_list.py:109
#: .\oam\views\setting\setting_list.py:49
 .\oam\views\stock\stock_list.py:75
#: .\oam\views\tom_article\tom_article_list.py:53
#: .\oam\views\transaction\transaction_list.py:90
msgid "Filter"
msgstr "Filter"

Running makemessages again of course leads into errors:
CommandError: errors happened while running msgmerge
c:\work\pro\apollo\oam\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:1915:3: syntax error
c:\work\pro\apollo\oam\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:1915: keyword "oam" unknown
c:\work\pro\apollo\oam\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:1915: keyword "views" unknown
c:\work\pro\apollo\oam\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:1915: keyword "stock" unknown
c:\work\pro\apollo\oam\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:1915: keyword "stock_list" unknown
c:\work\pro\apollo\oam\locale\de\LC_MESSAGES\django.po:1915: keyword "py" unknown
msgmerge: found 6 fatal errors

When removing the i18n at this line the makemessages works well:
filter_text = 'Filter'

I'm totally lost. Any hints? Thanks!

Have you tried to manually add # to corrupted string, and rebuild it after?

Yes, I edited the corrupt po file manualle by adding the "#:" prefix to the corrupt line. Then the subsequent compilemessages call works. But the next makemessages run leads always into the same problem.

In all po files (11 languages) I can see some lines like (2 files in one line):
#: .\oam\forms\article\article_import_check.py:19 .\oam\models\article.py:77
Is that correct? Usually only one one source file is referenced per line.
